# Why does my elementary cellular automata not display the right image given a certain rule-set?

Tags: c, simulation, wolfram-mathematica, cellular-automata

I have recently made a simple elementary cellular automata visualisation using the built in C console, a cell that is alive is a `@` and one that is dead is a space but for some reason it displays some random output to the console no matter which rule-set, the ones that seem to work are simple rule-sets such as rule 2. I do not yet know what might be causing the problem.

code:

```
int gen[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
           0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
           0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
           0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
           0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int ruleset[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0};
int size = sizeof gen / sizeof gen[0];
int alive=1;
int dead=0;

int rules(int a, int b, int c){
    if(a==1 && b==1 && c==1){return ruleset[0];}
    if(a==1 && b==1 && c==0){return ruleset[1];}
    if(a==1 && b==0 && c==1){return ruleset[2];}
    if(a==1 && b==0 && c==0){return ruleset[3];}
    if(a==0 && b==1 && c==1){return ruleset[4];}
    if(a==0 && b==1 && c==0){return ruleset[5];}
    if(a==0 && b==0 && c==1){return ruleset[6];}
    if(a==0 && b==0 && c==0){return ruleset[7];}
}

int main(void){
    int iterations;
    int procces;
    for(iterations=0;iterations<100;iterations++){
        for(procces=0;procces<size;procces++){
            int left=gen[procces-1];
            int right=gen[procces+1];
            int cell=gen[procces];
            
            gen[procces]=rules(left,cell,right);
            if(gen[procces]==0){
             printf(" ");
         }
         else{
            printf("@");
         }
        }
     printf("\n");
 }
}
```

Comment: You aren't handling the edge cases properly. The cell at `procces = 0` does not have a left neighbor, and the cell at `procces = size-1` does not have a right neighbor.

Comment: So then how should I do it?

Comment: What about making it a ring world? Insert code that uses gen[0] when procces+1 is 100, and gen[99] when procces-1 is -1.

Comment: I would reverse the order of your rules and have `return ruleset(a*4+b*2+c);`. But I think you can't beat a bit of bit-shuffling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've introduced a function that avoids out of range subscripts called `get_gen()`.

This one assumes everything beyond your array is barren 0.

For your rule the live cell 'moves' left and then falls out of the `world` at that barren edge.

As others point out you could execute on a ring.
You could even write a version that expands the world when the pattern expands beyond the space given.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int gen[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
           0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
           0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
           0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
           0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int ruleset[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0};
int size = sizeof gen / sizeof gen[0];
int alive=1;
int dead=0;

int rules(int a, int b, int c){
    if(a==1 && b==1 && c==1){return ruleset[0];}
    if(a==1 && b==1 && c==0){return ruleset[1];}
    if(a==1 && b==0 && c==1){return ruleset[2];}
    if(a==1 && b==0 && c==0){return ruleset[3];}
    if(a==0 && b==1 && c==1){return ruleset[4];}
    if(a==0 && b==1 && c==0){return ruleset[5];}
    if(a==0 && b==0 && c==1){return ruleset[6];}
    if(a==0 && b==0 && c==0){return ruleset[7];}
}

int get_gen(int pos,int *gen,int sz){
    if(pos<0 || pos>=sz){
        return 0;
    }
    return gen[pos];
}

int main(void){
    int iterations;
    int procces;
    for(iterations=0;iterations<100;iterations++){
        for(procces=0;procces<size;procces++){
            int left=get_gen(procces-1,gen,size);
            int right=get_gen(procces+1,gen,size);
            int cell=get_gen(procces,gen,size);
            
            gen[procces]=rules(left,cell,right);
            if(gen[procces]==0){
                printf(" ");
            } else {
                printf("@");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: But this still does not fix the original console displaying issue.

Comment: @BOOTRE What is that problem? It no longer displays junk and develops as your rule dictates. You've essentially defined a 'move live cells left' rule. See here https://ideone.com/Jym2lg

Comment: But if you run, for example rule 105, its result is completely different, your new function has provided nothing to the final console output, it is unable to display more complex rules as I previously mentioned in the question.

Comment: @BOOTRE On what initial condition? Do you mean this rule? http://atlas.wolfram.com/01/01/105/01_01_1_105.html#01_01_164_105. All isolated cells perish in that rule. So of course it goes empty with the initial generation provided.

Comment: Given the exact same initial conditions as the grid from the website you provided the output is completely different in the console, try it yourself, change the ruleset to `0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1` and see what happens, the output is completely different and incoherent.

Comment: @BOOTRE Sorry I see the problem. Your letting the partially determined generation affect the next generation. When you get pos-1 you're picking up the value for gen+1 not the current value in gen.

Comment: Try this https://ideone.com/Jym2lg  Now you get the pretty picture. Notice how it's now remembering what the left cell was not using what it is.

Comment: @BOOTRE Forgot to tag you. Now I understand!